# Web don't run immediately when using WebDriver driver.get(""")

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I just have learned about selenium.
My code:

```java
public class FirstTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(" YOUR USER NAME");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("YOUR PASSWORD");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='z0']/div")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_1 gb_3a gb_nc gb_e']/div/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
    driver.close();

    }

}
```

Issue is Firefox didnt run. I use Firefox 52.0.1 and Selenium 3.8.1 Anyone can check why for me !

After click run as java application:

[image: After click run as java application]

Comment: please add stack trace, some error which you got in your question

Comment: I suggest that you start [here](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-webdriver-comparison-selenium-rc.html).

Comment: Select `FirstTest - (default package)`